# Error Maintaining Checkbox state while paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, asp.net-ajax

I have visited various sites and found a lot of answers but none of them seems to solve my error.
I want to maintain the states of check boxes so that the number of check boxes checked before going to 2nd page remains the same when come back to 1st. My code is as follows:
Default.aspx file is:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"       CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DatabaseAndDataSourceControls._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET DatabaseAndDataSourceControls Demo<br />
        </h1>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringNorthwnd %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [City], [Country], [Phone] FROM [Customers]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [City], [Country], [Phone]) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName, @City, @Country, @Phone)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [CompanyName] = @CompanyName, [ContactName] = @ContactName, [City] = @City, [Country] = @Country, [Phone] = @Phone WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />


</DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringNorthwnd %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [ContactTitle], [Address], [City], [Region], [PostalCode], [Country], [Phone], [Fax]) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName, @ContactTitle, @Address, @City, @Region, @PostalCode, @Country, @Phone, @Fax)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([CustomerID] = @CustomerID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [CompanyName] = @CompanyName, [ContactName] = @ContactName, [ContactTitle] = @ContactTitle, [Address] = @Address, [City] = @City, [Region] = @Region, [PostalCode] = @PostalCode, [Country] = @Country, [Phone] = @Phone, [Fax] = @Fax WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactTitle" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Region" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="CustomerID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactTitle" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Region" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <h2>Manage Customers&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Height="25px" Text="Save" Width="80px" OnClick="Save_Click" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Check" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Height="25px" Text="Check" Width="80px" OnClick="Check_Click" />
        </h2>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBox">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="EmpSelector" runat="server" Text="EmpSelector"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument= '<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' CommandName="ViewDetails" Text="View Details" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" HeaderText="Customer Details" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle" SortExpression="ContactTitle" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="Region" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                No customer is currently selected.<br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New">New</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

And the CS file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace DatabaseAndDataSourceControls
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender,
        DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {       
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            savechkdvls();

            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

            chkdvaluesp();

            GridView1.DataBind();



        }

        private void chkdvaluesp()
        {

            ArrayList usercontent = (ArrayList)Session["chkditems"];

            //String index = "";

            if (usercontent != null && usercontent.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
                {

                    String index = (GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value).ToString();

                    if (usercontent.Contains(index))
                    {

                        CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("EmpSelector");

                        myCheckBox.Checked = true;
                        Label1.Text += index + " is checked </br></br>";

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        /////////////////////////
        private void savechkdvls()
        {

            ArrayList usercontent = new ArrayList();

            String index1 = "";

            foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                index1 = (GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value).ToString();

                bool result = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("EmpSelector")).Checked;


                // Check in the Session

                if (Session["chkditems"] != null)

                    usercontent = (ArrayList)Session["chkditems"];

                if (result)
                {

                    if (!usercontent.Contains(index1))

                        usercontent.Add(index1);

                }

                else

                    usercontent.Remove(index1);

            }

            if (usercontent != null && usercontent.Count > 0)

                Session["chkditems"] = usercontent;

        }

        protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            savechkdvls();

        }

        protected void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chkdvaluesp();
        }
    }
    }
```

I added two button Save and Check. So when I click them after moving the page from 2 to 1. The check box get updated. But checkboxes are not gettign updated without Save_click and Check_Click events. Please help.

Comment: Add int field in session which will store bitMask values, checkboxs will represent 1,2,4,8,16 and so on value. When you leave the page you save the value of selected checkboxes in the session, on opening you checked/mark them, depending on the bit mask value in the session.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured a more simpler way :)